# Be automatically notified about PFUser changing

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using Parse in my iOS application and I need to be notified when the user logout and login (so when the [[PFUser currentUser]](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users/iOS) changes as value).

The problem is that "currentUser" is NOT a property but a method so cannot be observed.

Do you know a way to be automatically notified about a user changing?

I tried to search on the Parse doc but I didn't find about any notification fired by the Parse SDK. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You control the logout and login, so you know when it happens. You can post your own notifications when the event occurs. It will be easiest if you have a class which deals with this and you set a convention where you always use that class rather than using `PFUser` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about this solution. I guess it's the best implementation. Thanks.